# Can I run two seperate jupyter notebook files at the same time, without slowdown on a single CPU computer?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

I am currently running a python function in jupyter notebook, which is taking quite some time. Python says it is running at about 98% of the CPU, however, still about 60% of my CPU is unused. Now after some googling I have found that this has to do something with threading of my processor (I am not a computer engineer so sorry if this is incorrect). However, **I was wondering if can run another function in jupyter notebook, and will it take up some of that 60% unused activity, or will it divide the 99% among two functions, slowing down both functions**. I hope you guys can help. If anything is unclear please let me know.

P.S. I am using a macbook pro retina late 2012 (i know), 2,5 gHZ intel core i5, with 8 gbs of ram. It has two cores and one processor.

Comment: sorry switched it up. Will change it !

Comment: Did you try it to see what would happen?

Comment: I was a bit anxious as I already had more than 21 hours of calculation time in the program. But I just tried it and it worked! Thanks! Both are running at 100%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an Intel Sandybridge or Ivybridge CPU.  It has two physical cores with hyperthreading, so it probably appears as 4 logical cores to the OS.

Each core has its own private L1i/d and L2 cache, but L3 (and memory bandwidth) is shared between cores.

Running a separate process or threads on the other physical CPU can slow down the first one by these mechanisms:

- dual-core max turbo clock speed is lower than single-core turbo.
- they compete for memory bandwidth and L3 cache footprint.  (i.e. more L3 cache misses).

If L3 cache misses and memory bandwidth aren't significant bottlenecks for your workload, then using both cores for separate tasks is pretty much pure win.

Running 4 threads (so the OS will have to schedule tasks onto both logical cores of each physical core) will give some slowdown, but it depends a lot more on the details of the workload.  See Agner Fog's microarch guide (http://agner.org/optimize/) for the asm / cpu-architecture details of how HT statically partitions or dynamically shares various execution resources.  But really just try it and see.

Probably a single thread has some stalls for cache misses and other bottlenecks other than pure throughput, so you could gain some throughput at the expense of single-core performance with hyperthreading.